# He was indicted for dealing in narcotics. (sementic group)

Tags: phrase-usage

> He was indicted for **dealing in** / narcotics.

or

> He was indicted for dealing / **in narcotics**.

Do we have to stop after 'dealing in' or 'dealing'? (sementic/breath group)

Comment: I think you mean "sem**a**ntic".

Comment: Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantic group is "in narcotics".

The verb is "deal" --not "deal in"-- and it takes the preposition phrase "in narcotics" as an *adjunct*.

Answer (score 1):

*Deal in* is not an idiom or complex verb. *In narcotics* is a constituent of the sentence an adjunct to the verb *dealing* so it would be perverse to break during it and not before it.

Comment: 'dealing' is a gerund since it was used after the preposition 'for'

Comment: @BEBYGONES: yes, _dealing_ is what some people call a gerund. That doesn't stop it from being a verb.

Comment: @ColinFine: Gerund is a noun that also has the charactersitc of a verb. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @BEBYGONES: or it's a verb that also has the characteristic of a noun.

Comment: @ColinFine: Yes, you are right. But a gerund is different from a verb in their form(v-ing) and usage.

Comment: And it's different from a noun in that it can take direct objects. I'm not sure why we're having this discussion: I used a hypernym, you prefer the hyponym. I don't particularly care either way.